# Doxygen 1.8.13 very slow performance when building against C# code base

Tags: c#, doxygen

We have been using Doxygen 1.8.8 for some time now with our large C# solution. Our Doxygen build time is about 2 minutes.

We recently upgraded to 1.8.13 and now have a Doxygen build time of around 7 hours for the same C# solution. We have had to downgrade to resolve the issue.

It seems this has been asked before:

[Is Doxygen build performance are affected by many "using" directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42034114/is-doxygen-build-performance-are-affected-by-many-using-directives)

Has anyone else experienced this issue and, if so, is there a work-around or plan to fix?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds very much like a bug in Doxygen. I recommend opening a new issue in the [Doxygen Issue Tracker](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen) and add as much information as possible.

Comment: Before submitting an issue please try with the current master version from github to see whether or not the problem has been resolved in the mean time.

Comment: ok thank you both - I will try to build this and if it still is an issue will raise